# How can I set the id of certain DIVs to be the same as repective parent DIVs?

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I currently have two posts on my blog. The markup of the posts is as follows (stripped down a bit):

```
<div class="post audio" id="post_27">
    <div class="subpost">
        <div class="jp-jplayer">
            <!-- Other unimportant code -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="post audio" id="post_26">
    <div class="subpost">
        <div class="jp-jplayer">
            <!-- Other unimportant code -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var post_id = $(".jp-player").parents(".audio").attr("id");
    $(".jp-jplayer").attr("id", "jp_" + post_id);

    $("#jp_" + post_id).jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                m4a: "media link..."
            });
        },
        swfPath: "/feathers/audio/jplayer",
        supplied: "m4a",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_" + post_id,
        wmode: "window",
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true
    });
});
```

I want to know how I can use jQuery to set the ids of the **jp-jplayer** DIVs to be the same as their respective **audio** parents. This has been bothering me for hours now so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The question reads as if you want the relevant child elements to have the same `id` as their parent element? If I've understood your question as you meant it, then that would result in invalid HTML (an `id` *must* be unique within the document).

Comment: @david-thomas Yes and no. I'm trying to get the id of each respective DIV's parents, and then append jp_ to it. The intended result would be two .jp-jplayer DIVs, one having the id "jp_post_26" and the other having "jp_post_27".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this -

```
$(".jp-player").prop('id',function(){
  return "jp_" + $(this).closest('.audio').prop('id');
})
```

Comment: Where do I place that in my script?